# Input validation and repetition in vba

Tags: vba, validation, excel

I have the following code and I would like help in 4 areas:

> 1. Did I validate the inputbox correctly? It should only take positive numerical variables.
> 2. How can I let the input box accept both input with, and without, symbols such as ($)?
> 3. How can I link the code so that it can directly request another number if the user has entered a negative non numeric number?
> 4. How can I repeat the procedure in the loop directly without repeating the whole code?

```
Option Explicit

Sub IncomeSalaryCalculation()

Dim strSalary As String
Dim dblTaxableSalary As Double
Dim dblTax As Double
Dim dblSalaryAfterTax As Double
Dim strOutput As String
Dim SalaryCalculationRequest As VbMsgBoxResult

strSalary = InputBox("Please indicate your salary", "Salary Calculation")

If Not IsNumeric(strSalary) Then
    MsgBox "This is no number! Please enter a non-negatif number", vbOKOnly, "Error"

ElseIf strSalary < 0 Then
    MsgBox "You should enter a positive number", vbOKOnly, "Error"

Else

dblTaxableSalary = CDbl(strSalary)

Select Case dblTaxableSalary
      Case Is >= 151000
               dblTax = 2440 * 0.1 + (37400 - 2440) * 0.2 + (150000 - 37400) * 0.5 + (dblTaxableSalary - 150000) * 0.5
      Case Is >= 37401
               dblTax = 2440 * 0.1 + (37400 - 2440) * 0.2 + (dblTaxableSalary - 37400) * 0.4
      Case Is >= 2441
               dblTax = 2440 * 0.1 + (dblTaxableSalary - 2440) * 0.2
      Case Else
               dblTax = 2440 * 0.1
End Select

dblSalaryAfterTax = dblTaxableSalary - dblTax

strOutput = "The amount of income tax is " & dblTax & vbNewLine & "Your salary after tax is " & dblSalaryAfterTax

MsgBox strOutput, vbOKOnly, "Final Salary"

Do

SalaryCalculationRequest = MsgBox("Do you want to calculate the tax of a new income?", vbYesNo, "New income tax salary calculation")

If SalaryCalculationRequest = vbYes Then

         strSalary = InputBox("Please indicate your salary", "Salary Calculation")

         dblTaxableSalary = CDbl(strSalary)

         Select Case dblTaxableSalary
          Case Is >= 151000
                   dblTax = 2440 * 0.1 + (37400 - 2440) * 0.2 + (150000 - 37400) * 0.5 + (dblTaxableSalary - 150000) * 0.5

          Case Is >= 37401
                   dblTax = 2440 * 0.1 + (37400 - 2440) * 0.2 + (dblTaxableSalary - 37400) * 0.4

          Case Is >= 2441
                   dblTax = 2440 * 0.1 + (dblTaxableSalary - 2440) * 0.2

          Case Else
                   dblTax = 2440 * 0.1

        End Select

        dblSalaryAfterTax = dblTaxableSalary - dblTax

        strOutput = "The amount of income tax is " & dblTax & vbNewLine & "Your salary after tax is " & dblSalaryAfterTax

        MsgBox strOutput, vbOKOnly, "Final Salary"

Else
     MsgBox "Glad to serve you"

End If

Loop Until SalaryCalculationRequest = vbNo

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Do not use irrelevant tags. This is VBA, VB.NET has no say here.

Comment: What errors you have?? How you tried to acomplish this???? We are not a resource site, we help you to fix the errors you have, and give answers to your questions, we don't do the job for you. Please read this [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should answer your questions without delving into all your code. Tested.

```
Sub getInput()
Dim ans As String

Do
   ans = InputBox("Please indicate your salary", "Salary Calculation")
Loop Until isValid(ans)

''{{{{{{{{
''Do what you need here with the user input (stored in *ans* variable)
''}}}}}}}}

End Sub

Function isValid(ans As String) As Boolean
   Dim cleanAns As variant
   cleanAns = IIf(ans Like "*$*", Replace(ans, "$", ""), ans)
   isValid = IsNumeric(cleanAns) And cleanAns > 0
   If Not isValid Then MsgBox "only positive numbers allowed"
End Function
```

Comment: No problem. If you want to allow additional currency you can duplicate the line that contains $ and replace the $ with another symbol.